# Why do I get NameError: name '_' is not defined when setting custom templates for djangocms-video?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms, python-3.9

I am trying to get custom templates working for djangocms-video.

So far there is a fresh djangocms project set up with some bootstrap and running fine.

According to the [readme](https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-video/blob/master/README.rst) we would need to specify this in the settings.py to make a custom template available (in this case a template named "feature"):

```
DJANGOCMS_VIDEO_TEMPLATES = [
    ('feature', _('Featured Version')),
]
```

After setting this and running manage.py this error comes up:

```
    ('feature', _('Featured Version')),
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

[According to other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995888/name-is-not-defined/12995923) we would need to import gettext like this in the modely.py:
`from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`
or like this:
`django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy  as _`

No luck so far. What am I missing here?

Here is some info on the environment:

```
python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

```
pip list
Package                    Version
-------------------------- -----------
asgiref                    3.4.1
cssselect2                 0.4.1
dj-database-url            0.5.0
Django                     3.1.14
django-classy-tags         2.0.0
django-cms                 3.8.0
django-filer               2.1.2
django-formtools           2.3
django-js-asset            1.2.2
django-mptt                0.13.4
django-polymorphic         3.0.0
django-sekizai             2.0.0
django-treebeard           4.5.1
djangocms-admin-style      2.0.2
djangocms-attributes-field 2.0.0
djangocms-bootstrap4       2.0.0
djangocms-file             3.0.0
djangocms-googlemap        2.0.0
djangocms-icon             2.0.0
djangocms-installer        2.0.0
djangocms-link             3.0.0
djangocms-picture          3.0.0
djangocms-style            3.0.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor    4.0.0
djangocms-video            3.0.0
easy-thumbnails            2.8
html5lib                   1.1
lxml                       4.7.1
Pillow                     9.0.0
pip                        21.3.1
pkg_resources              0.0.0
pytz                       2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim      0.1.0.post0
reportlab                  3.6.5
setuptools                 44.1.1
six                        1.16.0
sqlparse                   0.4.2
svglib                     1.1.0
tinycss2                   1.1.1
tzdata                     2021.5
tzlocal                    4.1
Unidecode                  1.1.2
webencodings               0.5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, the [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) is often imported as `_` to manage translations. This is explained in the [*Standard translation*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation):

> Python’s standard library `gettext` module installs `_()` into the global namespace, as an alias for `gettext()`. In Django, we have chosen not to follow this practice, for a couple of reasons
>
> (…)
>
> Because of how xgettext (used by makemessages) works, only functions that take a single string argument can be imported as `_`:
>
> - [**`gettext()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext)
> - [**`gettext_lazy()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy)

You thus should add:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

at the top of the file.

If you thus define something like `_('Featured Version')`, you can run [**`makemessages`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages) to generate translation files and fill in the translation per language.

Comment: Thanks @willem-van-onsem, the models.py of the djangocms-video project has that defined, you can find it on line 12 in the code:
https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-video/blob/master/djangocms_video/models.py#L12
That is exactly why I'm scratching my head here…

Comment: @4L3XK: but you need to import this in the `settings.py` as well. Each time you use it in a file, you need to import it in that file. It does not import it in some sort of "global" scope.